# How facebook change CDN url onclick on Facebook Page Messenger photos?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy, puppeteer

Facebook Page messenger or Chat is different than Facebook general messenger at least how it handles attachments. Unfortunately Facebook doesn't provide any archiving or backup facility for Business Page chat conversations. While doing some analysis on Facebook Page Chat messages I have found out that it stores the images in their CDN.

Image (uploaded by Message Sender) url formation is like this in the source :

```
  <div class="_4tsk _52mr _1byr" role="presentation"
 style="background-image: url(&quot;https://scontent.fdac6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-0/p280x280/121225341_3673506796007407_1092871686958271417_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&amp;ccb=2&amp;_nc_sid=ae9488&amp;_nc_ohc=QBvNLDzxvxwAX860K-T&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.fdac6-1.fna&amp;tp=6&amp;oh=f59aecb5459908f1c696414ca7cab47d&amp;oe=5FDD68D7&quot;);">
 <div class=""></div><a aria-label="Open Photo" class="_4tsl" target="_blank"
     href="https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent.fdac6-1.fna.fbcdn.net%2Fv%2Ft1.15752-0%2Fp280x280%2F121225341_3673506796007407_1092871686958271417_n.jpg%3F_nc_cat%3D111%26ccb%3D2%26_nc_sid%3Dae9488%26_nc_ohc%3DQBvNLDzxvxwAX860K-T%26_nc_ht%3Dscontent.fdac6-1.fna%26tp%3D6%26oh%3Df59aecb5459908f1c696414ca7cab47d%26oe%3D5FDD68D7&amp;h=AT1SrAioJpYtFuJ-4J-ktrvGoHXP1VlJgk3hyU0Mi7d83md8XI5vk8apwBeN6GaQfTyWBic6GLQNS4_XgjcZM-fcXuWEFkh_n_VO-OPEvwvdCdZAHD46Rf6_ih7jtqksW5w"
     rel="nofollow noopener" data-lynx-mode="hover"></a>
 <div style="max-width: 100%; width: 280px;"><img class=" _52mr _1byr _5pf5 img" alt=""
         src="https://scontent.fdac6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-0/p280x280/121225341_3673506796007407_1092871686958271417_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&amp;ccb=2&amp;_nc_sid=ae9488&amp;_nc_ohc=QBvNLDzxvxwAX860K-T&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.fdac6-1.fna&amp;tp=6&amp;oh=f59aecb5459908f1c696414ca7cab47d&amp;oe=5FDD68D7"
         style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
```

background image, url and image  all referenced to 280px x 280px image

```
https://scontent.fdac6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-0/p280x280/121225341_3673506796007407_1092871686958271417_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&ccb=2&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=QBvNLDzxvxwAX860K-T&_nc_ht=scontent.fdac6-1.fna&tp=6&oh=f59aecb5459908f1c696414ca7cab47d&oe=5FDD68D7
```

But If I click on the image link it opens different (I think the the **original size**) image url in this case -

```
https://scontent.fdac6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-0/p480x480/121225341_3673506796007407_1092871686958271417_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&ccb=2&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=QBvNLDzxvxwAX860K-T&_nc_ht=scontent.fdac6-1.fna&tp=6&oh=613ab8c45a65240e040b2d7d5338a7d6&oe=5FDD0F46
```

I have checked the difference between these two image urls are the last two parameters

**280px x 280 px**

```
oh=f59aecb5459908f1c696414ca7cab47d&oe=5FDD68D7
```

**480px x 480 px**

```
oh=613ab8c45a65240e040b2d7d5338a7d6&oe=5FDD0F46
```

How this 480px x 480px or original image url link is generated? I searched source for any entry of both parameters but couldn't found any. Is the redirection based on click event only?